# Combinations of a string double loop (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, loops, combinations

I'm trying to understand how to find all the combinations of a string using a double loop but the solution I've come across is too complicated for my understanding. The function does what I need but I have beginner understanding of setting up a single or double for loop.

I'm hoping for a general step by step explanation of what is going on but for specific questions: what functions are "i < **Math.pow(2,n)-1**", "((i & (1 **<<** j)) == 1 **<<** j)", and "var comb = ''; (temporary storage?)" serving?

```js
subsets = function(str) { 
      var n = str.length;
      for (var i=1; i< Math.pow(2,n)-1; i++) {
        var comb = '';
        
        for (var j=0; j<n; j++) {
          var use = ((i & (1 << j)) == 1 << j);
          if(use)comb+=str.charAt(j);
        }
        console.log(comb);
      }
    }
    
    subsets("age");
```

Output: a ag ae g ge e

Comment: Your output is in the wrong order.must be a g  ag e ae eg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a random combination of the string, we could set up a boolean array, storing if one of the characters should be displayed or not, e.g:

```
"a","g","e"
[true,false,true]
=>"ae"
```

So the number of possible variations is

```
2 /*true/false*/ ** str.length
```

written in old style:

```
Math.pow(2,str.length)
```

So the main for loop iterates over all possible combinatons except the first one (as i starts with 1),as that would be an empty string and the last one (-1) that would be "age". While i is an integer which simply counts up, we could also imagine that its a boolean array (in a bitwise view):

```
integer
bits
boolean array

1
001
[false,false,true]

2
010
[false,true,false]

3
011
[false,true,true]

4
100
[true,false,false]

... 
6 < 2 ** 3 -1
110
[true,true,false]
```

Now the inner loop:

```
for (var j=0; j<n; j++) {
  var use = ((i & (1 << j)) == 1 << j);
  if(use)comb+=str.charAt(j);
}
```

Just goes over our letters and checks if the boolean flag is true, so at i = 5 the boolean array would be:

```
[true,false,true]//101
```

and that is converted to

```
"ae"
```

How it looks bitwise:

A true one ("a"):

```
 101 // i
&001 //1<<j where j is 0
=001
===
 001 //1<<j
```

A false one ("g"):

```
 101
&010 //1<<j where j is 1
=000
!==
010 //1<<j
```

A true one ("e"):

```
 101 // i
&100 //1<<j where j is 2
=100
===
 100 //1<<j
```

So it checks if the boolean array (i) is true at js index, if so it adds that letter. BTW shorter:

```
 if(i & (1<<j))
```

Comment: Amazing explanation Jonas :) I've only just grasped the concept of how numbers are represented and operated on with bits and the Big O(2^n -1) binary tree branching options ....something something. What would a "higher level?" double loop look like without bitwise operations and the i < 2^n -1 "breaking point?". Something like "i < 6 loops due to 3 chars in the input" and the "var use" using some kind of non bitwise logical expression. Do you understand what I mean, as in a more second week of javascript double loop answer to the problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
var i=1; i< Math.pow(2,n)-1; i++
```

What the Math.pow(2, n) - 1 is saying is run this loop until (2^n)-1, where 'n' is the length of the string. So with the input 'age', the first for loop will run while i, starting at 1 and incrementing by 1 each loop, is less than (2^3)-1. Therefore, this first loop will run 6 times.

```
var comb = ''
```

Is exactly what you think it is - storage for what to log that populates as the for loops do their thing!

As for `(i & (1 << j)) == 1 << j)`, that's where we get into [Bitwise operators!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) Unfortunately, I don't understand these nearly well enough to explain them :(

Comment: *Unfortunately, I don't understand these nearly well enough to explain them :(*, at least youre honest, +1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Math.pow is a power function. The first argument is the base, and the second argument is the exponent, so Math.pow(2, n) is equivalent to 2^n. In the loop, `i< Math.pow(2,n)` means the boundary of the for loop is while i is less than 2^n, where n is the string length.

`var comb = '';` is initializing an empty string. This string is concatenated later in the loop so this declaration serves to establish that variable for concatenation.

Comment: By concatenation do you mean comb concat's a to e to make "ae" to output as part of the whole result, or it concat's (or holds/collects) the collection of result as it loops through to find the combinations, such as "a ag ae g ge e" to output onto the console?

Comment: @springathing the first

Answer (score 1):

It's a code based on binary (0/1) 
[operators in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Op%C3%A9rateurs/Op%C3%A9rateurs_binaires)  explain << it's a "Shift a into binary representation of b bits to the left, by inserting zeros by the right"
and & : Returns a 1 for each bit position for which the corresponding bits of the two operands are 1.

If u had some problem to undestand a code, Try it on paper step by step with simple example.
Try example str = "a", after try "on" ...

```
For "a" the beginning is 
 var n = str.length; // 1
for (var i=1; i< Math.pow(2,n)-1; i++) { // for i=1;i<2^1-1 =2-1=1;i++
var comb = '';
for (var j=0; j<n; j++) {//for j=0;j<1;j++
var use = ((i & (1 << j)) == 1 << j);// use = 1 & (1 << 0 insert 0 times 0)) == 1 << 0= (1 & 1)== 1=true (1==1)
if(use)comb+=str.charAt(j);//comb='' + a.charAt(0)=  comb= '' + "a"='a'
```

... You continue the loops.

binary is a method to write number with 0/1 :

Example 00101(binary)

U have 5 digits then the 1rst 0 = 0*2^(number of place of digit from right-1) = 0*2^4=0

> Then 00101(binary) = 0*2^4 + 0*2^3 + 1*2^2 + 0*2^1 + 1*2^0
>
> ```
>                = 0     + 0     + 1*4   + 0     + 1*1
>
>                = 5 in current using (decimal)
> ```

U find lot of explanation on binary with Google

Comment: Please fix formatting. *00101(binary) = 0*2^4+0*2^3+1*2^2+0*2^1+1*2^0=0+0+1*4+0+1*1=5* is not understandable